# How can I position a body of text to be in the middle and the logo, to the left side across from the nav bar in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position, text-alignment

I'm having a hard time practicing and can't figure this out to save my life. 7 hours trying to find solutions to no avail! Nothing will budge.

I simply want the text to be in the middle like this site or this site [a link](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-lead-better-user-interviews). Instead of all white I want an opaque black box with text over it. My text is just all over the place. And the logo on the left and the nav bar/ menu to the right of it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXgMS.jpg
Link to the code.
https://codepen.io/admitdefeat/pen/BEyMzK

HTML

```
<div class="post-body">
  <p>Do you need something done to your home or around your home? Do you feel as if your home doesn't have the same appeal as when you got it? Call our team of professionals and we can do what is needed to your home, yard and business that will improve
      its look and how you feel when you see it!</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
post-body{    
  padding-top: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
```

Thank you.

I've watched videos on how positioning, divs, containers and tried putting information together.However, there is something I'm not understanding.

I want the page to be aligned and positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't get stressed out, if you want the menu to be always on top right just give it the rules:

```
`#menu{
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px; /* or the amount you want */
    top: 5px; /* or the amount you want */
}`
```

apply the same logic on the logo, and finally add `text-align: center;` for your text to be centered in the page, and voila !

Comment: Thank you so much! It won't quite get in that top left corner but do you have any idea why this image won't get below the text?https://imgur.com/a/vFfeS0u

Answer (score 0):

In your `.post-body` class, remove the `padding-top: 3rem` and `position: relative` as they are messing up your formatting. Then add `text-align: center` to center the text on the page, and add `margin: 100px 20%` to restrict the positioning of the text. You can change both of these values to whatever you desire, depending on the positioning you are aiming for. The first value (100px) is how far from the top you want the text to begin (y-axis), and the second value (20%) is how far from the left and right edge you want the text to be (x-axis).

Note that using a % value for the second value will dynamically resize the text for you depending on the screen size. In this case, it will always be 20% of the screen size from the left and right edge of whatever device you are using.

```css
  body {
  font-family: "Basier";
  font-size: 20px;
}

html {
  background: url(summer.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.post-body {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px 20%;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Basier";
  src: url("basiersquare-regular-webfont.ttf");
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 140 px;
}


/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0 px;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Basier";
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

li:hover a {
  background: #F4D03F;
}


/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  background: #F4D03F;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: f1c40f;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}


/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}


/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}


/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Basier";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F4D03F;
  background: #F4D03F;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}


/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>CLT Designs</title>
  <link href="hoise.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="designs.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <img class="logo" src="clt.png" alt="logoclt">

  <h2> RENOVATION PROJECT</h2>
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="thahomepage.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="ABOUT.html">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">What is Design + Build?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Process</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="post-body">
    <p>Do you need something done to your home or around your home? Do you feel as if your home doesn't have the same appeal as when you got it? Call our team of professionals and we can do what is needed to your home, yard and business that will improve
      its look and how you feel when you see it!</p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing it with absolute and relative positioning, hope this solves your question. i modified your code just a little bit.

Check this codepen
   https://codepen.io/jls314/pen/oOgVGz

You wanted the logo to the left and the navbar to the right so I put them together in a header tag and position them.

```
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="clt.png" alt="logoclt">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="thahomepage.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="ABOUT.html">About</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">What is Design + Build?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Process</a></li>
  </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

this is the CSS:

```
header {
    position: relative;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}

.post-body{    
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You really just helped me in like 2 seconds.  Do you have any idea why this image won't get below the text?imgur.com/a/vFfeS0u I tried float, bottom but that didnt work.https://codepen.io/admitdefeat/pen/BEyMzK

Comment: I don't know if there is a float:bottom I think it's only left or right. but in the CSS code, the logo is already in absolute positioning with 10px from the left.

Comment: Which text do you want the image to be put above?

Comment: i meant align middle, bottom,sorry  i have 50 tabs open haha. its adding to my confusion. i wanted the image to be below the text. but <img src="design.png" alt="house example" align="bottom"> isnt working

Comment: assign your image to a class named below_text or whatever you want to define it.
    `<img class="below_text"`>

and then try styling and positioning it using your CSS code 
      `.below_text{}`

Comment: I put display:block; and that makes it go under without messing with the text but it won't get in the center? positioning is what i need to work on.

Comment: An upvote and voting this as an answer is so much appreciated! :D

Comment: Depends on the size of your image. If its too big, it would overlap with the text.